# How to make custom view call both its touchEvent and its parent's?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view, ontouchlistener, android-nestedscrollview

I'm currently working on a project where I have a custom view (graph). It is located inside a `RecyclerView` which is inside a `NestedScrollView`. My `GraphView` has an `onTouch` event that allows to see additional info while you're dragging your finger over values. When I was initially trying to implement it I would frequently receive an `ACTION_CANCEL` which was due to parent view interfering with its scrolling. After that I found a hacky solution which was to disable the parent controls at all with `requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true)`.

But this solution isn't exactly what I'm looking for. Instead I would want my app to have both at the same time. So, basically, custom view would keep showing additional data and have its `onTouchEvent()` triggered but my `RecyclerView` or `NestedScrollView` would still be scrolling if it received a drag by y axis.

Is it possible to implement this kind of a behavior and what would I need to do exactly?

Comment: You should share some code.

Comment: @Praveen the problem has nothing to do with code for now. Everything that is needed is put in the question. Adding my code won't help as it will only polute the question. And the question is: is it possible to trigger both view's onTouch?